# R) How to move 2 unique values in unique id as two new columns for that unique ID?

Tags: r, dplyr

```
z <- c("1001","1001","1002","1002")
h <- c("Yes","No","Yes","No")
count <- c("300","200","500","100")
df = data.frame(z,h,count)
df
      z   h count
  1 1001 Yes   300
  2 1001  No   200
  3 1002 Yes   500
  4 1002  No   100
```

Here I have two values in the "z" column that are repeated, but with different values in "h" and "count". I want to create two new columns called "h2" and "count2" that has the unique values for each unique id in "z". Here is the expected result. How would I write this in code?

```
           z  h count   h2    count2
      1 1001 Yes   300  No    200
      2 1002 Yes   500  No    100
```

Comment: You can use `pivot_wider` i.e. `library(dplyr);library(tidyr);library(data.table); df %>% mutate(rn =rowid(z)) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = c(h, count), names_sep="")`\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `pivot_wider()` function

```
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(h),values_from = c(h,count)) %>% 
  rename(z=z,h=h_Yes,h2=h_No,count=count_Yes,count2=count_No)
```